# I'd like to have a bigquery query code to join and calculate 2 tables

Tags: sql, join, google-bigquery, union-all

I have 2 tables in Bigquery and I'd like to merge/join them and doing some calculation.
Here are the tables :

Table A

| ID | Name | Score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12-2112 | John | 23844 |
| 12-2310 | Matthew | 21881 |
| 13-6205 | Matthew | 16721 |
| 12-1710 | Sonia | 13344 |
| 12-1710 | Sonia | 8187 |

Table B

| ID | Name | Games | Score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12-2112 | John | Soccer | 10291 |
| 12-2112 | John | Soccer | 2271 |
| 12-2112 | John | Soccer | 3211 |
| 12-2112 | John | Soccer | 1625 |
| 12-2310 | Matthew | Tennis | 11551 |
| 12-2310 | Matthew | Volley | 2232 |
| 12-2310 | Matthew | karate | 1861 |
| 12-2310 | Matthew | Judo | 2081 |
| 13-6205 | Matthew | MMA | 5281 |
| 13-6205 | Matthew | Racing | 8681 |
| 13-6205 | Matthew | Volley | 1921 |
| 12-1710 | Sonia | football | 3324 |
| 12-1710 | Sonia | Volley | 2716 |
| 12-1710 | Sonia | Judo | 6718 |
| 18-1130 | Sonia | football | 4281 |
| 18-1130 | Sonia | Tennis | 3199 |

The score on Table A is the total score of games of Table B. However, not all games on Table B is identify.
So, the final table should look like :

Combined

| ID | Name | Games | Score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12-2112 | John | null | 6446 |
| 12-2112 | John | Soccer | 10291 |
| 12-2112 | John | Soccer | 2271 |
| 12-2112 | John | Soccer | 3211 |
| 12-2112 | John | Soccer | 1625 |
| 12-2310 | Matthew | null | 4156 |
| 12-2310 | Matthew | Tennis | 11551 |
| 12-2310 | Matthew | Volley | 2232 |
| 12-2310 | Matthew | karaté | 1861 |
| 12-2310 | Matthew | Judo | 2081 |
| 13-6205 | Matthew | null | 838 |
| 13-6205 | Matthew | MMA | 5281 |
| 13-6205 | Matthew | Racing | 8681 |
| 13-6205 | Matthew | Volley | 1921 |
| 12-1710 | Sonia | null | 586 |
| 12-1710 | Sonia | football | 3324 |
| 12-1710 | Sonia | Volley | 2716 |
| 12-1710 | Sonia | Judo | 6718 |
| 18-1130 | Sonia | null | 707 |
| 18-1130 | Sonia | football | 4281 |
| 18-1130 | Sonia | Tennis | 3199 |

I've tried all the joining statements possibles (I know) but the output is not as desired.

The best I did found was a union all (or distinct) with this query :

```
select
ID,
Name,
null as Games,
Score
from Table A
Union ALL
Select
ID,
Name,
Games,
Score
from Table A
```

and here is the output :

| ID | Name | Games | Score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12-2112 | John | null | 23844 |
| 12-2112 | John | Soccer | 10291 |
| 12-2112 | John | Soccer | 2271 |
| 12-2112 | John | Soccer | 3211 |
| 12-2112 | John | Soccer | 1625 |
| 12-2310 | Matthew | null | 21881 |
| 12-2310 | Matthew | Tennis | 11551 |
| 12-2310 | Matthew | Volley | 2232 |
| 12-2310 | Matthew | karaté | 1861 |
| 12-2310 | Matthew | Judo | 2081 |
| 13-6205 | Matthew | null | 16721 |
| 13-6205 | Matthew | MMA | 5281 |
| 13-6205 | Matthew | Racing | 8681 |
| 13-6205 | Matthew | Volley | 1921 |
| 12-1710 | Sonia | null | 13344 |
| 12-1710 | Sonia | football | 3324 |
| 12-1710 | Sonia | Volley | 2716 |
| 12-1710 | Sonia | Judo | 6718 |
| 18-1130 | Sonia | null | 8187 |
| 18-1130 | Sonia | football | 4281 |
| 18-1130 | Sonia | Tennis | 3199 |

The score is not the total of table A - Sum (of Games) score of Table B as expected.

Could you please help me out ?

Thanks

I'm trying to joing query statement between table A and table B and have the score of table A to be the difference from the sum (table A) - sum (table B) for a null "games"

I've tried the following query :

```
select
ID,
Name,
null as Games,
Score
from Table A
Union ALL
Select
ID,
Name,
Games,
Score
from Table A
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider below simple approach

```
select id, name, games, 
  if(not games is null, score, 2 * score - sum(score) over(partition by id, name)) as score
from (
  select * from tableB union all
  select id, name, null, score from tableA
)
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]